# Como retornar uma SQL com resultado?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, select

Eu preciso selecionar várias tabelas ligadas pela "id do usuário" e retornar os dados para compôr uma página de perfil, porém alguma dessas tabelas podem estar vazias em um primeiro momento, ou seja, a consulta não vai encontrar a "id do usuário" em uma delas e vai retornar um erro ou nenhum dado. Como eu posso selecionar várias tabelas retornando a consulta independente dos dados encontrados ou não?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenho um exemplo de uma situação parecida que passei.
voce deve usar o `left join`:

```
SELECT PERMISSAO.Codigo CODIGO,
       PERMISSAO.Descricao DESCRICAO,
       ISNULL(permissaoUsuario.acesso, 'N') ACESSO
  FROM permissao 
  LEFT JOIN permissaoUsuario ON PERMISSAO.Codigo = permissaoUsuario.codpermisao
   AND permissaoUsuario.codusuario = @CODUSUARIO
 WHERE PERMISSAO.DATAEXCLUSAO IS NULL
```

Nesse exemplo eu usei o `left join` (trazer da esquerda) para trazer as permissoes da tabela `PERMISSAO` mesmo que o registro não esteja inserido na tabela `PERMISSAOUSUARIO`